# Why numpy.flip() reduces the memory size of a NumPy array without change its precision and shape

Tags: python, numpy, memory, sparse-matrix, numpy-ndarray

I wrote a function to transform sequential data into a sparse matrix. And I surprisingly found that `img = np.flip(img, axis = 0)` reduce the matrix memory size from 1928 to 128.

Also, no matter how I increased the length of the time window (the width of the sparse matrix), the memory size of the final flipped matrix is always 128.

I thought that the `np.flip()` only created a view of the original matrix, which means that the memory size should be changed, so I don't understand why this happened.

The function is given below

```
def gen_img(df, index, interval, height):
    df = df[index-interval+1: index+1, :5]
    max_price = df[:, 1].max()
    min_price = df[:, 2].min()
    if max_price == min_price:
        return df, np.zeros((height, interval * 3), dtype="float32")
    else:
        df[:, :4] = np.around((height * 4 / 5) * (df[:, :4] - min_price) / (max_price - min_price) + height / 5)
        df[:, 4] = np.around(df[:, 4].astype("float32") * height / 5 / df[:, 4].max())
        df = df.astype(int)
        img = np.zeros((height, interval * 3), dtype="float32")
        print("check zero matrix size: {}".format(sys.getsizeof(img)))
        for i in range(interval):
            img[df[i, 0], i*3] = 1.0
            print("check intermed1 matrix size: {}".format(sys.getsizeof(img)))
            img[df[i, 3], i*3 + 2] = 1.0
            img[df[i, 2] : df[i, 1] + 1, i*3 + 1] = 1.0
            img[0 : df[i, 4] + 1, i*3 + 1] = 1.0
        print("check intermed2 matrix size: {}".format(sys.getsizeof(img)))
        img = np.flip(img, axis = 0)
        print("check generated matrix size: {}".format(sys.getsizeof(img)))

    return df, img
```

And here is the debug print out

```
check zero matrix size: 1928, dtype: float32, shape: (30, 15)
check intermed1 matrix size: 1928, dtype: float32, shape: (30, 15)
check intermed1 matrix size: 1928, dtype: float32, shape: (30, 15)
check intermed1 matrix size: 1928, dtype: float32, shape: (30, 15)
check intermed1 matrix size: 1928, dtype: float32, shape: (30, 15)
check intermed1 matrix size: 1928, dtype: float32, shape: (30, 15)
check intermed2 matrix size: 1928, dtype: float32, shape: (30, 15)
check generated matrix size: 128, dtype: float32, shape: (30, 15)
```

Comment: It is just a view—that’s precisely why its size is small and fixed.

Comment: `sys.getsizeof` takes *way* more in-depth expertise to use correctly than it looks.

Comment: @DavisHerring Thanks for your help! I'm not familiar with pointer and memory allocation. Since I assign a view to the original variable, no variable refers to the original matrix, would it be collected as garbage?

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for your help! Is there any way to check the actual memory consumption of a variable?

Comment: The databuffer of the original matrix won't be garbage collected because the view is still using it.  Whether the 128 byte 'overhead' is collected or not is a trivial matter..  `x=np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)` is a view of the original, unnamed `arange`.  `x.base` will show you that..  `flip` is a view that reverses one dimension, e.g. `data[:,::-1,:]`.

Comment: 'actual memory consumption' needs a clearer definition.  What is it for a `view`?  Just added array overhead, or that overhead plus the base's databuffer?  `getsizeof` measures one thing, `nbytes` another.  Overall `getsizeof` does better with arrays than with python classes like `list` and `dict`.

Comment: I've seen many SO about `sys.getsizeof`, and rarely has it provided any useful information.  For numpy arrays it is easy to get the memory use with `nbytes` and a basic understanding of when something is a view or not.  `sys.getsizeof` usually is more confusing than helpful.